# How do you add values to a pivot chart without summarizing?

Tags: c#, excel

I'm writing a program that creates three different arrays of randomly generated numbers; one for 5 items, one for 25 items, and one for 50 items. This is done multiple times based on a set number of iterations that are passed to the program {10,100,1000}.  So essentially, I have 9 sets to go through... {5,10},{5,100},{5,1000},{25,10},{25,100},{25,1000},{50,10},{50,100},{50,1000}...

For each of the sets, I log the time before and after each array is sorted and sum them up at the end.  This give me the total runtime that it took for each of the sets.  I store the data in a Data Table and export it to Excel using columns A1:C10 (Headings are included).

Here's where I get stuck... the data has to be charted.  I've attempted to make a pivot chart using the data on the spread sheet.  I've set the legend to the number of items in each array (5,25,50) and the X-Axis to the number of iterations each of the arrays is passed through (10,100,1000).  I've formatted the Running Time column to a custom format using: "h:mm:ss.000.000.000".

When I set the values field of the Pivot Chart to running times, it summarizes by 'Count', 'Sum', or some other built in function, but I need the actual values to display for the chart to be effective.  I've posted a screen shot below of some of what I'm doing so you can get an idea.

I have attempted to use the DataChart in the c# tool box, but apparently I'm too thick to grasp it.  So I've now begun attempted to do it directly in Excel, but can't seem to get a hold of it either.

[image: Columns In Excel]
[image: Pivot Chart Attempt]

Thanks in advance,
Runnin

Comment: In your particular example it looks like you have a 1:1 value for runtime. Make sure you format your values the correct time. If there is only one value then a SUM will work.

Another option would be to make the rows or columns more unique if you have more data. 

Use an Average possibly? 

Don't use a pivot and chart the direct numbers.

Comment: Thanks Razor, you were right about the Pivot Chart, it was steering me in the wrong direction.  I guess the automation of everything hides what's going on in the background.

Sorry, but I don't know how to upvote a comment...